# Should I be using wsHttpBinding or wsDualHttpBinding for methods that return values?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to write a host/client style system with WCF and I currently want to use the wsHttpBinding but I was reading up about something else (the isOneWay bool) when I cam across this line:

'HTTP can't be used for callbacks and therefore you can't use callbacks over BasicHttpBinding or WSHttpBinding'

Most of my methods will return values, for example the client would call a method which would send back specific data from the server depending on the method called. Like this, with a return line in:

```
public string SayHello(string name)
{
    Console.WriteLine(">>> SayHello has been called");
    return string.Format("Hello, {0}!", name);
}
```

Would the return line make it a callback so would I have to use a different binding? Or is a callback only when the client sends a 'message' to the server and the server sends a 'message' back? In my code it is just calling the method which returns data so would that not be classed as a callback and I can continue to use the wsHttpBinding? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely don't need `wsDualHttpBinding` to return values. `BasicHttpBinding` or even better `WSHttpBinding` is what you need

`wsDualHttpBinding` is used to actually call the client from the server (callbacks). It's something which isn't widely used in the web world because it has limitations and there are better options like WebSockets and SignalR

Comment: Ah, thank you, that clears it up. So it is basically like a prompt to tell the host to send the data to the client?

Comment: `wsDualHttpBinding`? It's more like a way to message back. It doesn't have to be right after the client calls the server.

Comment: You can use it for example to for notifications, or something similar.

Comment: No, the wsHttpBinding is just like a prompt to tell the method to send data to the client so it wouldn't be a callback.

Comment: oh.. something like that. The client sends an http message and gets a response containing the result. But all that is abstracted for you. You just call the method on the client and "magically" get a result from that method.